# Autostart html5 video on a Webview not working on Android 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, html5-video

I am using an Android [html5Webview](https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/) with html5  element.

I am auto-playing the video from javascript (when the page loads) using this code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play();
```

(taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/aprock/5913322):).

This works perfectly on Android 4.1.2 (Samsung Galaxy 3, note2). On Android 4.2.2 (Galaxy S4, Nexus 10), the video does not auto-play. It does start playing when clicking the screen.

I tried adding timeout to the play event, it did not work.
Any ideas what could be the cause of it?

tnx!
Yaniv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer was [here](https://gist.github.com/aprock/5913322).

The autostart did not work on regular javascript page load event, but did work when triggered from within Android's "onPageFinished" event.

Answer (score 1):

For Jelly Bean and above, this can easily get the job done:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Please note that you should add the 'autoplay' attribute to the video tag in order for this to work in this case. TNX!